# R: Survfit function - getting p value when specifying start.time

Tags: survival, logrank-test

I would like to make a Kaplan-Meier curve for data on an alternate timescale. I'm interested only on events happening after 6months followup, so I use the `start.time=0.5` option.

```
form=Surv(time, isdead) ~ surgeries_yn
a$call$formula <- form
fit <- survfit(form, data = data, start.time=0.5)
```

Making the log rank test
*surv_pvalue(fit2)*
I realized that, whatever the value I enter for start.time the returned Pvalue is always the same!
As difference between the curves seems to be time dependent (i.e.curves are similar in the beginning and become more different after a certain time) I don't understand this result.

Any idea why?

Comment: Please show more details of the analysis results with and without the "start.time = 0.5" setting. Also, please specify how many cases have event times less than 0.5 for each of your `surgeries_yn` groups, and the total number of cases in each of those groups. Add that information by editing the original questions, as comments are easily overlooked and can even be completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you provide code that runs, both because it makes it easier to follow and because it tells us what packages are involved: `survfit` is in the recommended package `survival`, but `surv_pvalue` isn't -- I'm assuming you mean the function of that name in the `survminer` package.

Looking at the documentation for `survminer::surv_pvalue`, it does not mention `start.time`, and looking at the code, it doesn't take account of the `start.time` argument in the `survfit` call. So this won't work.

You can use `survival::survdiff`. Working with the `aml` dataset on the `survfit` help page, and comparing time starting at 0 and at 40

```
> survdiff(Surv(time,status)~x,data=aml)
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

                 N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
x=Maintained    11        7    10.69      1.27       3.4
x=Nonmaintained 12       11     7.31      1.86       3.4

 Chisq= 3.4  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.07 
> survdiff(Surv(time-40,status)~x,data=subset(aml,time>40))
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time - 40, status) ~ x, data = subset(aml, 
    time > 40))

                N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
x=Maintained    3        1     2.35     0.776      4.26
x=Nonmaintained 2        2     0.65     2.804      4.26

 Chisq= 4.3  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.04
```